# Substitute for load_pem_private_key() in golang

Tags: go, openssl, rsa, pem

I have this code in python

```
privateKey = appAuth["privateKey"]
passphrase = appAuth["passphrase"]

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key
key = load_pem_private_key(
  data=privateKey.encode('utf8'),
  password=passphrase.encode('utf8'),
  backend=default_backend(),)
```

I want to replicate this in golang.
Basically I have this:-

```
"appAuth": {
  "publicKeyID": "2qwqckds",
  "privateKey": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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\nn74=\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "passphrase": "2788518b2900d77fafc71dbf4f764927"
}
```

In golang, I have tried this so far:-

```
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(privateKey)) \\ privateKey is a string
key, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
```

But it doesn't work.
Please Help.

Comment: "it doesn't work" meaning what exactly? What problem are you having?

Comment: You have to [decrypt](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#DecryptPEMBlock) the key before you can parse it.

Comment: @Peter: that routine as described is for _PEM-level_ encryption, which OpenSSL uses for 'legacy' format privatekeys; the data here is **PKCS8** encrypted format, which is encrypted (and decrypted) differently (and not the whole block, only part) and on that page I see routines for PKCS8 _unencrypted_ but not PKCS8 _encrypted_. OP: are you using OpenSSL (or compatible)? Can you convert the key to 'legacy' PEM-encrypted PKCS1, and Peter's approach should work on that?

Comment: @Adrian It is returning an error "tags don't match (2 vs {class:0 tag:16 length:64 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} int @2"

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right, that "DecryptPEMBlock" doesn't work (I have tried that). It expects "DEK-Info header", which is not present in my key.
Actually this key is part of a json, that is supposed to be used to make jwt request (To use [Box](http://box.com/) API). Here is an example of someone doing it in python [(Example)](https://github.com/box-community/samples-docs-authenticate-with-jwt-api/blob/master/sample.3.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decrypt encrypted pkcs8 key (an example of such key is mentioned in the question) in go 
there is an awesome library https://github.com/youmark/pkcs8/.

```
import "github.com/youmark/pkcs8"
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(config.BoxAppSetting.AppAuth.PrivateKey))
decryptedPrivateKey, err := pkcs8.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes, []byte(config.BoxAppSetting.AppAuth.PassPhrase))
```